# Is it possible to add a click event to an image?

Tags: javascript

I have an image and I want it to add a list item to the UL when it's clicked. It's not working.

HTML and JavaScript are as follows:

```js
const myList = document.querySelector('ul');
const imageClick = document.getElementById('test');

imageClick.addEventListener('click',() => {
  myList.innerHTML = '<li>This goes on the list</li>';
});
```

```html
<ul class='list'>
</ul>

<img src ='imgs/test.jpeg' alt = 'an image' 
id='test'>
```

I'd create a JSFiddle but I'm not sure how to add dummy images and show any of value that would explain it better.

Comment: That should work, you just need to make sure that your javascript is after your html unless you are using onload method to attach event.

Comment: Lots of sources on web for placeholder images that can quickly be used to create a demo

Comment: My javascript is linked before the closing of my body tag.